# Redirect with URL parameter added

Tags: .htaccess, google-analytics, http-status-code-301

In order to see in Google Analytics how many 301 forwards happen from olddomain.com to newdomain.com I understand that I can [add a url parameter](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/27459)

However the following doesn't seem to work on the homepage, only subpages:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1?utm_source=olddomain.com&utm_medium=redirect [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Your help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does it do when you go to `http://olddomain.com/`? Are there other rules?

Comment: Hi Jon. Those are the entire contents of the .htaccess file. When I go to olddomain.com it simply goes to newdomain.com without the url parameters.

Comment: Are there any `Redirect` directives or `RedirectMatch` directives anywhere? in htaccess or in vhost/server config?

Comment: Not that I know of. Could it be the .htaccess file on the new domain?: `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Campaign tracking requires 3 parameters: `utm_source, utm_medium, and utm_campaign`

Currently, you are only including `utm_source` and`utm_medium` which is probably why you are seeing inconsistent results.

See [Tracking 301 Redirects with Google Analytics](http://www.lanevance.com/web/web-development/tracking-301-redirects-with-google-analytics/) for this example:

`RewriteRule ^$ http://www.lanevance.com/?utm_source=redirects&utm_medium=lanevance.me&utm_campaign=301_Redirects [R=301,L]`

The [URL Builder](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1007028&answer=1033867) from Google is also very helpful.